# How can I post a user name for my account

Tags: support

Currently I am listed as "user23299429", because I had difficulty when signing in. I would like to be listed as "Still curious at 82". Please let me know if, and how, this can be done.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the site! Your username can be changed in a couple quick steps by [going to your profile page and editing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/85820/274942). You can choose whether you'd like to apply the change to just one Stack Exchange community or all of them. Note that you can only change your username once every 30 days, though.